# XYZ da Vinci 2.0 Duo Y-axis slipping

Tags: y-axis, xyz-da-vinci-2.0-duo

I have a "da Vinci 2.0 Duo" that when I start a print or jog is okay. But when it finishes the brim, it starts to slip on the Y-axis, the print then begins to shift farther back and it happens again in the same spot making it like multiple shadows. I have checked the belt tension and connections but nothing has worked

Comment: Could you [edit] in a photo so we can see what exactly is happening? This will help to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: This sounds like layer shifting, good that you checked the belt, maybe adding a photo may help to diagnose the issue!